# How can I add webhook events to a flask server?

Tags: python, events, flask, webhooks, server-side

I have been searching everywhere for tutorials on how to create and implement webhooks which listen for events within a back-end API. For instance, if I had a server written in python flask, how would I listen to server-side events (example: user has created 100 total records) which then executes some more back-end code or requests external data?

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {"status": 200}

#Some webhook code listening for events in the server


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What do I write to listen for server events?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/signals/

Comment: Thanks. That is essentially is what i'm looking for.

Comment: I am happy that I did help you! I will create the answer, so you may accept it :)

Comment: Funny enough, knowing about signals 2 years a go could have made me rich, well, at least I can rest in peace now haha

Answer (score 2):

You can use flask feature called `before_request` it like this

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, current_app, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.before_request
def hook_request():
    Flask.custom_variable = {
        "message": "hello world",
        "header": request.args.get("param", None)
    }


@app.route('/')
def home():
    variable = current_app.custom_variable
    return jsonify({
        "variable": variable,
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and to test it
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJUoe.png)

```
→ curl http://localhost:5000/  
{"message":"hello world"}

→ curl http://localhost:5000\?param\=example
{"variable":{"header":"example","message":"hello world"}}
```